# How to give seperate action for selections(select event) in Struts2 (used in an autocompletion text box)

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, autocomplete

I have an text box which is autocomplete enabled from DB. I'm using Javascript to enable autocomplete functionality.

```
$("#loanApplicationNo").autocomplete("<s:url action="/suggestByLoanApplicationNo"/>",{maxItemsToShow : 5});
```

When I type some thing on the textbox, choices will appear in the text box and when I choose/select a particular result, I want a seperate action to be called.

```
<s:textfield name="loan.applicationNo" id="loanApplicationNo" theme="simple" />
<a id="depositSearch" class="example6 cboxElement" href="/casba-pa-war/ln/3106.action?from=7005" title="Customer Accounts Search" style="padding-left: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 12px;">
    <img alt="search" src="../images/search.jpeg" border="0px"/>
</a>
```

How can I achieve this.I tried a lot but failed to fire a seperate action for selection.

Answer (score 0):

The `url` tag is used to build and render the action ready URL from the action name and/or namespace attributes, and also could be parametrized. The `action` attribute should contain the valid action name not the path.

```
$("#loanApplicationNo").autocomplete({
 source: function(request, response) {
   $.getJSON('<s:url action="suggestByLoanApplicationNo"/>', {
     term: extractLast(request.term)
   }, response); 
 }
});
```

The action should return `json` result that is available if you configure the package to extend the `json-default`.